# php intl change field length but not position

Tags: php, date, format, intl

I have a quite strang question regarding date formatting in `intl` extension.

I see that several default `date formatter` exist but none matches my need.
I need a date format with the following field lengths: **day 2 digits**, **month 2 digits**, **year 2 digits**.

Unfortunately SHORT format returns a 2 digits year output.

So I was wondering if it's possible to customize field length without modifying locale positioning given by default settings; i.e. I'd want to manage to return:

```
11/16/2012 in en_US and 16/11/2012 in it_IT
```

instead of

```
11/16/12 in en_US and 16/11/12 in it_IT
```

Thanks for your answers.